# Netbeans doesn't recognize import java.awt.event.ActionEvent and import java.awt.event.ActionListener

Tags: java, netbeans

I have created a JButton and I want to perform an action every time I click on it.
I choose from Properties actionPerfomed and then I try to write the code inside the function.

```
 private void OnMusicActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        MusicType = "on";
    }
```

NetBeans though doesn't recognize the imports for ActionEvent and suggests that I should create a new class.
What is wrong?

Comment: What is the error message you are seeing?

Comment: I press alt+enter in java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt and netbeans suggests that I should create a class ActionEvent in java.awt.event

Answer (score 1):

It'll be helpful if you provide little more details in you question.

I am guessing you need another class which implements ActionListner, for example something like this:

```
private class ACListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
```

This link should help you as well : [examples](http://www.javabeginner.com/java-swing/java-jbutton-class-example)