# Netbeans does not see java.awt.event.ActionEvent in generated code

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-plugins, actionevent

I'm trying to create a plugin for NetBeans - a simple menu item when right clicking on a package opens a window from a library. Following [this](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-google.html) instruction I've went thought the action wizard and NetBeans generated this code:

```
package org.miku.testmodule;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import org.openide.awt.ActionID;
import org.openide.awt.ActionReference;
import org.openide.awt.ActionRegistration;
import org.openide.util.NbBundle.Messages;

@ActionID(
        category = "Build",
        id = "org.miku.testmodule.Test1"
)
@ActionRegistration(
        iconBase = "org/miku/testmodule/action 24x24.png",
        displayName = "#CTL_Test1"
)
@ActionReference(path = "Menu/File", position = 0)
@Messages("CTL_Test1=Test1")
public final class Test1 implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO implement action body
    }
}
```

This code however does not compile - it can't find both `java.awt.event.ActionEvent` and `java.awt.event.ActionListener` - causing more errors in the code.

I've tried looking at link from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13614559/4903564) on a similar problem, but it leads to a dead webpage.

Interestingly enough when I tried importing `java.awt.event.ActionEvent` in IntelliJ it worked fine without any additional libraries (but afaik you cannot make NB plugins in IDEA)

I'm using Apache NetBeans IDE 10.0

Tried on both JDK 11 and JDK 1.8

Comment: You probably want your "project" setup. In the end, the IDE has some issues resolving dependencies.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? How can I setup my project in NetBeans?

Sorry if it's obvious I usually don't use NB.